# setting up Elastic Cache in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elasticache

I have the same problem setting up Elastic Cache in AWS, I created one, set up a security group to allow inbound TCP to all TCP ports from my home IP. However, I can not telnet to that box. When I run the code, I got timeout error. Can you share with me  how did you set it up?

I tried Amazon Audo Discovery demo code as well as simple-spring-cache for memcached. I got timeout on both of them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to access Amazon ElastiCache from home network. You can access memcached instance on Amazon only from your EC2 instance.